# SQL Amazon BIE Interview Question Customer Table

Tags: mysql

**transactions** table

column       type
id          integer
user_id     integer
created_at  datetime
product_id  integer
quantity    integer

**users table**

column  type
id      integer
name    varchar
sex     varchar

***Write a query to identify customers who placed more than three transactions each in both 2019 and 2020.***

Output

column  type
customer_name   string

My code is：

```
WITH CTE AS( SELECT u.name, count(user_id) AS "Num_Apperence",YEAR(t.created_at)
             FROM transactions t
             LEFT JOIN users u 
             ON t.user_id = u.id
             WHERE YEAR(t.created_at) = 2019
             GROUP BY u.name
             HAVING count(user_id) > 3
)
SELECT Name1
FROM (SELECT u.name AS 'Name1', count(user_id) AS "Num_Apperence",YEAR(t.created_at)
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN users u 
ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE YEAR(t.created_at) = 2020
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING count(user_id) > 3) AS T
INNER JOIN CTE 
ON CTE.name = T.Name1
```

This is runnable, but cannot pass the test case. I was wondering, what is going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a single query with conditional aggregation to find users who placed more than three transactions in 2019 and 2020:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(created_at) = 2019 THEN 1 END) > 3 AND
           COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(created_at) = 2020 THEN 1 END) > 3
)

SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON t.user_id = u.id;
```